# Cannot add a symbol to indicate a dashtable column is editable

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have following editable dash datatable:
[image]

However it is not clear for other user that the entries of last two columns can be modified manually, if the user wishes to do so. In the following screenshot, I have changed manually the red marked entries.
[image]

Is there a way to add the following symbol
[image] so that it's clear that the entries of last two columns (not the columns name) are editable.

My current code for this datatable is:

```
dash_table.DataTable(
                id='growth_pe',
                # columns=[{'name': i, 'id': i} for i in growth_pe_table.columns],
                columns = [
                    dict(id='company', name='Company'),
                    dict(id='historical_growth_rate', 
                        name='Historical EPS Growth Rate\n (min, mean or annualized, max)'),
                    dict(id='historical_pe',
                        name='Historical PE\n (min, mean, max)'),
                    dict(id='annual_growth_rate',
                        name='Annual EPS Growth Rate\n %', type='numeric', 
                        format=percentage, editable=True),
                    dict(id='pe', name='PE', editable=True)
                ],
```

Thank you for any suggestions.

---

Solution:

After doing some research, there is now no way to add icon into dashtable header, which would be perfect for my problem. The current best solution is in my opinion to colour the editable columns and use a tooltip:

```
        tooltip_header={
                'historical_growth_rate': 'If (1 + EPS Growth Rate) > 0\
                     -> Annualized growth rate, if < 0 -> Mean value',
                'annual_growth_rate': {
                    'value': 'This column is editable. \n\n For 12.7% \
                    Growth Rate, enter: 0.127\n\n![edit]({})'.format(
                        app.get_relative_path('/assets/images/Edit_Icon.jpg')),
                        'type': 'markdown'},
                'pe': {
                    'value': 'This column is editable.\n\n![edit]({})'.format(\
                        app.get_relative_path('/assets/images/Edit_Icon.jpg')),
                    'type': 'markdown'}
            },
        tooltip_delay=0,
        tooltip_duration=None,
        tooltip={
                    # column: {'value': 'This column is editable.\n\n![edit]({})'.format(
                    #     app.get_relative_path('/assets/images/Edit_Icon.jpg')),
                    #     'type': 'markdown'}
                    # for column in ['annual_growth_rate', 'pe']
                'annual_growth_rate': {
                    'value': 'This column is editable. \n\n For 12.7% \
                    Growth Rate, enter: 0.127\n\n![edit]({})'.format(
                        app.get_relative_path('/assets/images/Edit_Icon.jpg')),
                        'type': 'markdown'},
                'pe': {
                    'value': 'This column is editable.\n\n![edit]({})'.format(\
                        app.get_relative_path('/assets/images/Edit_Icon.jpg')),
                    'type': 'markdown'}
                },
```

In case someone would like to see how it looks like, the link to the webapp: https://gunardi-dashboard.herokuapp.com

The relevant code can be found here: https://github.com/gunardilin/valuation_dashboard/blob/main/Dashboard.py and look for the following keywords: `growth_pe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm yes I see how you got that SVG from the built-in feature where `dash datatable` allows you to toggle user-renaming of columns. I don't think there would be any simple (in Python) ways to also carry over that feature for the editing. I don't see styling code in your example given, so not sure how you colored the columns. But indeed there are built-in style parameters for color-highlighting specific cols/rows/cells, conditionally, or explicitly.

E.g., you could add something like the following:

```py
    style_data_conditional=[{
        'if': {'column_editable': True},
        'backgroundColor': 'rgb(30, 0, 0)',
        'textDecoration': 'underline',
        'textDecorationStyle': 'dotted',
    }]
```

where `style_data_conditional` is an attribute that would go within the parentheses of the `dash_table.DataTable`.

Another idea that comes to mind which would be pretty close is you could use the multi-headers feature, and have an extra header row underneath the main real one with the column names, and leave all non-editable columns blank, but use a unicode symbol to indicate the editable columns.

Ah! Or, actually, here's an even better and less hacky solution. How about conditional highlighting (by coloring and dashed underlining of column name(s)) plus a hoverable tooltip that will show the pencil image?

Here's an example:
[image]

```py
dash_table.DataTable(
    data=df_jobs.to_dict("records"),
    columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df_jobs.columns]
    + [{"name": "# of Openings", "id": "no_of_openings", "editable": True}],
    style_header_conditional=[
        {
            "if": {"column_editable": True},
            "backgroundColor": "rgb(250, 0, 0, 0.5)",
            "textDecoration": "underline",
            "textDecorationStyle": "dotted",
        }
    ],
    style_data_conditional=[
        {"if": {"column_editable": True}, "backgroundColor": "rgb(250, 0, 0, 0.25)"}
    ],
    # markdown_options={"html": True},
    tooltip_data=[
        {
            "no_of_openings": {
                "value": "![This column is editable](../assets/images/editable_dash_svg.png)",
                "type": "markdown",
                "delay": None,
                "duration": None,
            }
        }
    ],
),
```

I zoomed in real close and took a screenshot of the pencil, and put a copy of that as a png under my assets/images folder, and apparently the latest versions of dash datatable allow for markdown injection into tooltips, including linked images! You can further edit the formatting of the tooltip, making it smaller, and I would assume many other fine tuning things like adding a border and moving the coordinates of where it appears. Here's a link to those docs: [(See the "Styling" subsection in particular)](https://dash.plotly.com/datatable/tooltips).

Comment: Many thanks. Your suggestion with image inside tooltip and also colouring column are very good, it is not perfect but I believe it is the best currently available solution. I tried to add image to the header. I hope it will be possible in the future.

Comment: No problem it's a useful little Dash thing to know! As I alluded to, you can further change the styling of the tooltip -- it's probably quite customizable, depending on how much effort and knowledge of CSS you have time to apply to it!

Comment: I forgot to mention, instead of using "tooltip_data", I use "tooltip". Because that way, I can create a tooltip for ALL data cells of specified columns. That way I don't need to create an extra header just for showing the tooltip. I will add my code on my question...

Comment: Awesome, looks good! Also, from looking at and using devtools to inspect the tooltip on your app, I found the CSS selector which could be globally modified in .css file under /assets: `dash-tooltip .dash-table-tooltip {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    max-width: 300px;
    min-width: 300px;
    padding: 2px 10px;
}`